# Is Texmate obsolete?

Tags: chessboard

What is the status of the [`texmate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texmate) package?

Is it considered obsolete?

Looking for samples I find only 2; one is the Manual, the other a 2-page example also by the author, Frederico Garcia. Neither compiles without error on a recent Miktex installation.

I can compile both by commenting out offending code, however there seems to be a serious bug having to do with nested variations, first Level.

On the other hand, the package seems to have nice features...

`skak` seems to work. So should I stick to `skak`?

Comment: At first I thought you meant this: http://www.texmate.com/

Comment: I'm using [`xskak`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xskak) + [`chessboard`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chessboard) packages, if your question aims at typesetting chess diagrams.

Comment: Yes, texmate is for typesetting chess articles, diagrams and text. It builds on skak and chessboard, uses both.

Comment: xskak is not skak (but like texmate it uses skak). skak has been updated recently and now handles variations differently and this is probably the source of the problems in texmate. Did you try to contact the author?

Comment: No. Looks like he hasn't done anything with texmate since 2006. What is your advice? I don't want to fight (Major) Tex Problems. Just want to write chess text that Looks good.

Comment: I hadn't done anything with xskak since 2008 until I had to correct a bug some weeks ago. The last version of chessfss is from 2006 but if you would find a bug in it I would like to hear from you anyway. So write the author of texmate and give him a chance to correct the problem. The alternatives are skak and xskak.

Comment: I inadvertently let my contact details in the CTAN database go out of date but when somebody looked up my email address, I still responded to a feature request for one of my packages. And I'd not done anything to any of my packages for a few years. (Else CTAN would have had current contact details.) Don't assume the maintainer won't respond - if they think the package is working and aren't developing new features, they have no reason to 'do anything with it' if nobody reports the problem.

Comment: OK. I'll write to him.

Comment: After experimenting a bit I have come to the conclusion that xskak + chessboard serves my purpose better than texmate. The main Problem is that the source becomes unreadable, hence difficult to edit, due to the interlaced markers when mixing text and chess notation.